# Convert Umlaut in existing HTML String (Java function)

Tags: java, html, encode

I need a java function to convert umlaute in an existing html-String. So for example I have

```
<html>
<body>
äü
</body> 
</html>
```

Now the function should convert all types of umaute into its escaped form. So it should leave the html code intact but just replace a -> ä and ü -> ü in the above example resulting in

```
<html>
<body>
&auml;&uuml;
</body>
</html>
```

I am well aware of the fact that there are loads of escaping functions like in [escapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4(java.lang.String))
. The problem is that all html is converted so also the html code is escaped. I am looking for a function that identifies only the text-parts within the html code and then encodes them.

Furthermore setting the UTF-8 encoding is not an option for me in this case.

Comment: `yourString.replace("ü","&uuml");`

Comment: How to make sure to replace all available umlaut?

Comment: Repeat the same statement for ö and ä too

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse the html file first, and then apply escaping only on the relevant parts.

for example, [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html) is an html parser. You can iterate over the html elements, then and manipulate their content.

update: this turns out to be very simple with Jsoup:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class StackOverflow {

    static final String HTML = "<html><body>äü</body></html>";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
        doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.base);
        doc.outputSettings().charset("ASCII");
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
}
```

produces:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  &auml;&uuml;
 </body>
</html>
```

By setting the charset to ASCII in the output settings, your are telling Jsoup that it should output no UTF-8 characters. As a result, Jsoup escapes them.

Comment: How would I know if the element contains text and not html Code?

Comment: Jsoup transfoms your html text to a tree of java objects: at the root there is a `Document`, and the documents consists of a tree of `Elements`and `TextNode`. In your example, I guess that 'äü' would be a TextNode in the 'body' Element. You should then replace the content of the TextNode with their html escaped form, and recompose the HTML with your modified Tree.  Start by parsing your document ([Jsoup - parsing and traversing a Document](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document))

Comment: Turns out to be very simple using JSoup. See my updated answer.